# Flutter Camera recorded Video are incompatible with browsers - how to convert to .mp4?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to capture a video and upload it to firebase storage.

The problem is, the recorded video format is `.mov` and this format seems to be incompatible with browsers.

How could I convert the recorded file to `.mp4`?

Below is the code I use to record and upload my videos.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class CameraTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraTestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraTestPageState createState() => _CameraTestPageState();
}

class _CameraTestPageState extends State<CameraTestPage> {
  List<CameraDescription>? cameras;

  CameraController? controller;
  bool frontCamera = false;
  XFile? videoFile;

  VideoPlayerController? videoController;
  VoidCallback? videoPlayerListener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

  initCamera() async {

    if (cameras == null) {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
    }

    if (controller?.value.isInitialized ?? false) {
      controller!.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(
      cameras!.firstWhere(
        (element) => element.lensDirection == (frontCamera ? CameraLensDirection.front : CameraLensDirection.back),
      ),
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    controller!.initialize().then((value) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void onVideoRecordButtonPressed() {
    startVideoRecording().then((_) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void onStopButtonPressed() {
    stopVideoRecording().then((file) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (file != null) {
        print('Video recorded to ${file.path}');
        videoFile = file;
        _startVideoPlayer();
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _startVideoPlayer() async {
    if (videoFile == null) {
      return;
    }

    final VideoPlayerController vController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoFile!.path));
    videoPlayerListener = () {
      if (videoController != null && videoController!.value.size != null) {
        // Refreshing the state to update video player with the correct ratio.
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
        videoController!.removeListener(videoPlayerListener!);
      }
    };
    vController.addListener(videoPlayerListener!);
    await vController.setLooping(true);
    await vController.initialize();
    await videoController?.dispose();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        videoController = vController;
      });
    }
    await vController.play();
  }

  Future<void> startVideoRecording() async {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;

    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      print('Error: select a camera first.');
      return;
    }

    if (cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      // A recording is already started, do nothing.
      return;
    }

    try {
      await cameraController.startVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return;
    }
  }

  Future<XFile?> stopVideoRecording() async {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;

    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      return cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    print('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }

  _uploadVideo() async {
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("test/test.mov");
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(File(videoFile!.path), SettableMetadata(contentType: 'video/mov'));
    print("uploading");
    uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      String downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      print("download url: $downloadUrl");
    });
  }

  Widget _thumbnailWidget() {
    final VideoPlayerController? localVideoController = videoController;

    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            child: (localVideoController == null)
                ? Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text("none"),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: localVideoController.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(localVideoController),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Camera Test")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          if (controller != null)
            Container(
              child: CameraPreview(controller!),
              height: 400,
            ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  frontCamera = !frontCamera;
                  initCamera();
                },
                child: Text("Switch"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  controller?.value.isRecordingVideo ?? false ? onStopButtonPressed() : onVideoRecordButtonPressed();
                },
                child: Text(controller?.value.isRecordingVideo ?? false ? "Stop" : "Record"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: videoFile != null ? _uploadVideo : null,
                child: Text("Upload video"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          _thumbnailWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Before saving video to gallery, what is the format of the video that's uploaded to firestore?  I mean in what file format is flutter_camera saving your video?

Comment: @ANUPSAJJAN I just found out that the issue is that the recorded videos are of .mov format which seems to be incompatible with browsers. Now I need to find out how to convert to mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress) package to convert the video to mp4.

Here is your `_uploadVideo()` method updated to include this:

```dart
     _uploadVideo() async {
        Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("test/test.mp4");
    
        MediaInfo? mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
          videoFile!.path,
          quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality,
          deleteOrigin: false, // It's false by default
        );
    
        UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
            File(mediaInfo!.path!), SettableMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));
        print("uploading");
    
        uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
          String downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
          print("download url: $downloadUrl");
        });
      }
```

Ensure you import the package by including this line:

```dart
import 'package:video_compress/video_compress.dart';
```